# Is it possible to get redirected to a malware download URI while using Tor as a proxy?

Tags: malware, tor, antimalware

Now this is an interesting one. I just received a forwarded email notification from my data center provider that one of my servers accessed a sink hole that is associated with the nymaim malware. The notification came from the Bundesamt für Sicherheit in der Informationstechnik (BSI), Germany's Cybersecurity Authorities.

Since the machine is a docker host running all kinds of microservices but surely no MS Windows enviroment, I was kind of irritated because nymaim is (according to my research) all but not a linux based malware (am I correct with this?).

I kept thinking hard and came to the idea that one of the microservices that uses tor as a proxy and a selenium based browser to fetch (https) content might have received a malicious response from a fraudulent exit node which resulted in a redirect that pointed to the sink hole.

What do you guys think, is possible that this could be a vector that triggered the BSI notification?